# Is there any way that use apple watch to control iPhone?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

When I read a book on my iPhone, I don't want to turn the pages with my hands every time. As we know , we can take photos with iPhone and use apple watch to press the shutter. So Is there a way that I can scroll pages use apple watch's digital crown?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dunni Sorry , I'll ask the right place . thx.